# Retrieving attribute values from XML file using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I need help with this XML located [here](https://volby.cz/pls/prez2018/vysledky).

I want get attributes `JMENO` and `HLASY_PROC_1KOLO` of the `KANDIDAT` element:

What I've tried so far:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://volby.cz/pls/prez2018/vysledky");

foreach($xml as $item) {
   echo $item['CR'],"<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/ph7TSRnUnbP950OY) for an example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://volby.cz/pls/prez2018/vysledky");

foreach($xml->CR->KANDIDAT as $item) {
    $jmeno = $item->attributes()['JMENO'];
    $hlasy = $item->attributes()['HLASY_PROC_1KOLO'];
    echo $jmeno, ' : ', $hlasy, '<br />';
}
```

Comment: i love y boi <3